# Which is the easiest way to inject markup into an iframe with react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, reactjs

I'm using react to build an app that will allow the end user to enter their own html/css and I wanted to isolate their code from the main app via an iframe (yes i know saving markup to the database is bad, but it's required in this instance) so a user will enter their markup in a field and then I wanted that data to be pulled into the iframe via the server, but I've noticed that react doesn't play nice with iframes in that way `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` method but with no luck and accornding to caniuse `srcDoc` doesn't work in any version of IE/edge. also the method outlined here: https://developer.zendesk.com/blog/rendering-to-iframes-in-react but it seems extremely convoluted and fragile.

is there a way to inject markup into an iframe via react?

Comment: so as I understand you want to render some code pulled from Db into the actual running app ?